# Como enviar uma requisição POST a uma REST API em PHP?

Tags: php, rest

Considero bastante simples executar uma requisição GET, normalmente utilizo:

```php
    //$serverurl contem a url da api para a função desejada

    try {
        $cursos = file_get_contents($serverurl);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
```

Depois de obter um **json** de reposta, uso o `json_decode()` e trabalho esses dados.

Mas estou tendo dificuldades em executar uma requisição POST, onde preciso passar alguns parâmetros para o webservice.

Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de executar isso.

Se possível, não pretendia utilizar **curl** pois já me deparei com restrições onde não pude fazer uso dele...

Comment: Você utiliza Zend Framework?

Comment: Não pretendia utilizar nenhum framework...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Utilizei o seguinte trecho de código para fazer requisição POST para API:

```php
            $servidor = $_POST['servidor'];

            // Parametros da requisição
            $content = http_build_query(array(
                'txtXML' => $_POST['txtXML']
            ));

            $context = stream_context_create(array(
                'http' => array(
                    'method' => 'POST',                    
                    'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                                "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n".
                                "Content-Length: ".strlen($content)."\r\n",
                    'content' => $content                               
                )
            ));
            // Realize comunicação com o servidor
            $contents = file_get_contents($servidor, null, $context);            
            $resposta = json_decode($contents);  //Parser da resposta Json
```

Comment: @Guilherme É isso que você precisa?

Comment: Acredito que sim, @fymoribe. Vou deixar a pergunta aberta por enquanto porque só vou ter como testar novamente na api amanhã. Mas obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso com PHP, a forma mais comum é usando a biblioteca curl:

```
$url  = 'http://server.com';
$data = ['key' => 'value'];
$ch   = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

A curl fornece um client HTTP completo e flexível. Verifique a documentação da curl para explorar todas as funções disponíveis e as opções para customizar as requisições: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php

Apesar da curl ser fácil de usar, existem bibliotecas feitas em PHP, como o Guzzle, que fornecem uma camada de abstração orientada a objetos em cima da curl, tornando o código muito mais legível e elegante:

```
use Guzzle\Http\Client;

$client   = new Client('http://server.com/');
$request  = $client->post('users', $headers, $data);
$response = $request->send();
```

Aliás, o Guzzle também tem uma ótima documentação: 
http://guzzlephp.org/